# Rules of thumb for a proportion of outliers depending on the dimension

Tags: pca, outliers, dimensionality-reduction, robust, high-dimensional

I am implementing and benchmarking different "robust" PCA (principal component analysis, see for instance [Robust Principal Component Analysis?](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/RobustPCA.pdf)) for data that should align (I have no prior on the underlying distribution, except a linear aspect). I would like to isolate potential outliers based on their distance to the first principal vector. In one dimension ($n=1$), I could choose $p=10\%$ of points furthest from the median.

Are there rules of thumbs to propagate nicely such a proportion in higher dimensions $n$, like $p^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Comment: It really depends on the breakdown point of the method you are using. If the breakdown point is smaller than $k/n$ there is no point in trying to find more than $k$ outliers.

Comment: @user603 I understand, yet statistics sometimes have crude rule of thumbs. I was thinking about dimensionality-based ideas

Comment: the (finite sample) breakdown depends on the number of dimension. I'm not sure I understand the rest of your comment~